# How can I split this string as a UDF

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have this column (from an export from BigCommerce Database) that holds custom fields in a single column. Here's one example of the data:

```
[{"Name":"Unit Number","Value":"3698"},{"Name":"Region","Value":"Eastern Great Lakes (WNY, W PA)"}]
```

I need a way to figure out how to extract the Field/Value pairs from this. In this sample, I'd like to get, as output:

```
Unit Number:3698
Region:Eastern Great Lakes (WNY, W PA)
```

I'm hoping to have as a result a UDF that I can run as a part of a select query that gives me just the field name and the value output as a string (as exampled above). Every column of data in the source table has this format. Typically, the column data has two field/value pairs, but sometimes none, sometimes two, sometimes three. In other words, the column holds any number of variable field/value pairs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to build a UDF to help get those data elements out of this string?

I was tinkering around with things, but I'm stuck. I started with trying to remove the extraneous characters `[,]` which mean nothing, and `{,}` which delineate the field and the value. I was tinkering with string-split functions, but instead of splitting on a single character, I can't figure out how to split based upon pairs of open or closing brackets `{,}` to narrow it down.

```
Unit Number:3698 | Region:Eastern Great Lakes (WNY, W PA)
```

Comment: This appears to be JSON content.  Have you looked into using SQL Server's JSON functions?

Comment: MSSQL 2016 and above support JSON (which is what you have there), See JSON_VALUE()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  N'[{"Name":"Unit Number","Value":"3698"},{"Name":"Region","Value":"Eastern Great Lakes (WNY, W PA)"}]' 

--read from json
SELECT [Name], [Value]  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH ([Name] NVARCHAR(100) '$.Name',  
        [Value] NVARCHAR(50) '$.Value')  

--if it has only these two fixed cols like Unit Number, Region starts here
SELECT [Region],[Unit Number] from 
             (
                SELECT [Name], [Value]  
                    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
                      WITH ([Name] NVARCHAR(100) '$.Name',  
                            [Value] NVARCHAR(50) '$.Value') 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([Value])
                for [Name] in ([Region],[Unit Number])
            ) p 
--if it has only these two fixed cols like Unit Number, Region ends here

--********if it has dynamic columns starts here********
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Name])  
            FROM OPENJSON(@json)
              WITH ([Name] NVARCHAR(100) '$.Name',  
                    [Value] NVARCHAR(50) '$.Value') 

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT [Name], [Value]  
                    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
                      WITH ([Name] NVARCHAR(100) ''$.Name'',  
                            [Value] NVARCHAR(50) ''$.Value'') 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([Value])
                for [Name] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ' 

print @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@json NVARCHAR(MAX)', @json
--********if it has dynamic columns ends here********
```

Note: this will only work from MSSQL 2016/17 or above, used v17.1